# Porting Java NIO Files.walkFileTree visitor to C, maintaining thread-safety

Tags: c, filetree, directory-walk

I have some existing Java code that uses `java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree` with the `FileVisitor` interface, but now I need to port it to plain C.  Is there a C equivalent of this interface?  If not, what primitives can I use to build one?

I've looked at the Unix `ftw` and `nftw` functions, but it doesn't appear that they will work because the callback function doesn't have a parameter for supplying user variables (a single void* param would have been nice).  My code needs to be thread-safe.

Comment: Removing the `[java]` tag as the answer won't have anything to do with Java.

Comment: If all else fails you can use `ftw` in a thread-safe way. Store your user data pointer in thread-local storage, either with `_Thread_local` in C11 or with `pthread_setspecific()`. What you can't easily do is make such interfaces re-entrant too.

Comment: On a related note, I also found this nice [link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively) that shows how to do a recursive file tree walk in just about every language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had this need of file walking for one of my project. I also needed it to be portable on Linux and Windows.

I did not found an open source implementation for it and finally ended up implementing it myself. This was finally not too much work.

On the Linux side, I used `opendir()` and `readdir()` to iterate over directory entries.
On the Windows side, I used `FindFirstFileA()` and `FindNextFileA()` to do the job.
Next for each entry, I simply call a used defined callback.

Both implementations does not take much than 100 lines of code... So I would suggest you to DIY.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both the BSD operating systems and Linux supply a family of function called `fts(3)`, that do the same thing as POSIX `ftw` but without the inversion of control via callbacks. Instead, the paradigm is that you "open" an FS hierarchy to get a handle, then "read" entries out of that:

```
char *const roots[] = {root, NULL};  // fts allows for multiple roots
FTS *hier = fts_open(roots, FTS_PHYSICAL | FTS_NOSTAT, NULL);
FTSENT *entry;

while ((entry = fts_read(hier)) != NULL) {
    puts(entry->fts_path);
}
fts_close(hier);
```

IMHO, this is much cleaner than the visitor pattern, but for a direct port of your Java code you can of course implement that on top of `fts(3)`.

If your OS does not have `fts(3)`, then check out the [OpenBSD version of `fts.c`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/gen/fts.c?rev=1.44;content-type=text%2Fplain), which you should be able to paste into your program with at most minor modifications. You'll also need the header [`fts.h`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/include/fts.h?rev=1.14;content-type=text%2Fplain).

Comment: This was also useful information.  The only reason I didn't select this as the answer is because I ended up actually implementing the answer by @greydet

Answer (score -1):

If mixing in c++ is acceptable there is something in boost for doing this, never used it though.